# Trying to get app configurations in azure

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to get all the app configurations using get-azresource with type property. It is proving the result but values of many properties are not there for app configuration. I have also used expandproperties with get-azresource parameter but still didn't get desired result. How can I get it?

Comment: Actually there is an instance named app configuration in portal I was trying to fetch that but there is no such command to do it so I used get-azmetric but all its properties are not comming

Comment: What properties do you want? What is your desired result? Please don't let others to guess your requirement. May be a screenshot is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `Application settings`, you could use:

```
$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<webapp-name>/appsettings" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
$resource.Properties | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

If you want to get the `Connection strings`, you could use:

```
$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<webapp-name>/connectionstrings" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
$resource.Properties | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

[image]